# How to get values from different tables to the jTable.Netbeans and H2 database

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, h2

How to get values from different tables to the jTable?
Netbeans and H2 database.
I know how to do it with console,but how to do it with JFrame JTable-I don't understand. And where should this code  be?  Should it be new class for it or should  it be in JFrame?

Please help.

for example:

---

```
    package mainproject;
        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.SQLException;
        import java.sql.Statement;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class MainProject {

         @param args the command line arguments

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            HotelAdmin program = new HotelAdmin();
            program.table();
            Connection conn = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Statement stmt = null;




    try {  
                Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file://d:\\КУРСАЧ\\database", "sa", "");
            //create statement
            try{
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            }    catch (SQLException ex){
             Logger.getLogger(MainProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
             }  


           rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from people");



            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("id= " + rs.getLong("id_p") + ", FIO= " + rs.getString("fio") + ", pasportny dannye= " + rs.getString("pas_dan") + ", telefon= " + rs.getString("telef"));
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    if(conn !=null) conn.close();
                    if(stmt !=null)stmt.close();
                    if(rs !=null)rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you read the [Tutorial on JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: There are no words about database :(

Comment: So instead of using System.out.println() to display the data on the console you add the data to the TableModel. That is why you need to start with the basics of learning how a JTable works. Then getting the data from the database is then next step.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for some ideas.

I would start with the `TableFromDatabase.java` example code which only needs small modifications to access your database.